# Get and modify mouse or keyboard events while interacting with general system in Linux

Tags: c, linux, io, x11

I am using Ubuntu 20 LTS, trying to experiment with writing a script in C/C++ that can get mouse and keyboard events, then modify them, and then apply it to whatever **System wide** action is being performed .

For example: I was trying to create a mouse accelerator in in Linux with minimal use of any non-default packages available in Linux. for now I have found `X11` for my purpose.

**I am unable to find any solutions that work for the whole system**

The issue is that many functions grab the event so the mouse cannot interact with the environment and unable to modify the result until i ungrab it, like changing coordinates. eg: `XGrabPointer()` and are only localized to a single screen like the terminal. The code I am using below (`gcc app.c -lX11`) : -

```cpp
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);

    // Grab the mouse pointer
    XGrabPointer(display, root, False, ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask | PointerMotionMask,
                 GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, None, None, CurrentTime);
    XGrabKeyboard(display, root, True, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, CurrentTime);

    XEvent event;
    KeySym key;
    KeyCode keycode;
    u_int32_t cntr = 0;

    while (cntr < 1000) {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);

        switch (event.type) {
        case ButtonPress:
            keycode = event.xkey.keycode;

            // Check the mouse button pressed
            switch (event.xbutton.button) {
            case Button1: // Left mouse button
                printf("Left mouse button pressed\n");
                XUngrabPointer(display, CurrentTime);
                break;

            case Button2: // Middle mouse button
                printf("Middle mouse button pressed\n");
                break;

            case Button3: // Right mouse button
                printf("Right mouse button pressed\n");
                break;

            default:
                printf("Unhandled mouse button: %d\n", event.xbutton.button);
                break;
            }

            break;

        case KeyPress:
            keycode = event.xkey.keycode;
            printf("Key event, keycode: %u\n", keycode); 

            // Check if the pressed key is Escape (ESC)
            if (keycode == XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_Escape)){
                printf("Cosed\n");
                // Release the mouse pointer grab and close the display
                XUngrabPointer(display, CurrentTime);
                XUngrabKeyboard(display, CurrentTime);
                XCloseDisplay(display);
                return 0;
            }
            break;

        default:
            printf("Unhandled event type: %d\n", event.type);
            break;
        }
        cntr++;
    }

    // Release the mouse pointer grab when done
    XUngrabPointer(display, CurrentTime);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

I have also tried using `<X11/extensions/XInput2.h>` but it has the same issue of not working outside the running script window, either not updating state in same display or giving error if using multiple screens. relevent script as follows (`gcc move_cursor.c -lX11 -lXi`): -

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XInput2.h>

int main(){
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    if (display == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open display.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int opcode, event, error;
    if (!XQueryExtension(display, "XInputExtension", &opcode, &event, &error)){
        fprintf(stderr, "X Input extension not available.\n");
        XCloseDisplay(display);
        return 1;
    }

    Window root = RootWindow(display, DefaultScreen(display));

    XIEventMask evmask;
    unsigned char mask[(XI_LASTEVENT + 7) / 8] = {0};
    evmask.deviceid = XIAllDevices;
    evmask.mask_len = sizeof(mask);
    evmask.mask = mask;
    XISetMask(mask, XI_Motion);
    XISelectEvents(display, root, &evmask, 1);

    XEvent ev;

    int cntr = 0;
    while (cntr < 1000){
        XNextEvent(display, &ev);

        if (ev.xcookie.type == GenericEvent && ev.xcookie.extension == opcode){
            if (XGetEventData(display, &ev.xcookie)){
                if (ev.xcookie.evtype == XI_Motion){
                    XGetEventData(display, &ev.xcookie);
                    printf("Mouse coordinates (%d): X=%d, Y=%d\n", cntr, ev.xmotion.x, ev.xmotion.y);
                    XFreeEventData(display, &ev.xcookie);
                }
                XFreeEventData(display, &ev.xcookie);
            }
        }
        cntr++;
    }
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to know how I should approach the issue. should I use something else? I also found `fcntl.h` https://www.ibm.com/docs/vi/aix/7.2?topic=files-fcntlh-file file but I am not sure how relevant it is to my problem or how I can use it effectively. I am also unable to find a exhaustive tutorial or video which does this. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Ever heard about [libevdev](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libevdev/)? What do you mean by "_System wide action_"?

Comment: @ErdalKüçük by "System wide action" i meant any click or key press performed while a normal user is doing normal tasks on any application or on the desktop itself. i don't want it bound to a specific app. 

i wasn't aware of libevdev. thanks, i'll look into it. any tutorial or blog  you recommend?

Comment: No, nothing i could recommend, but the [API documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/libevdev/doc/latest/) is very comprehensive, take a look at it. So, i would recommend to start with the Modules page of the API documentation.